# How to start a new session in servlet after Google OAuth "Sign in with Google"

Tags: java, web, tomcat, servlets, google-oauth

I'm still very new to web development and trying to add a "Sign in with google" button to my login page. I am using Apache Tomcat v10 Java Servlets for my backend.

The button itself works fine and I can grab the user's email in , but I need to create a new HttpSession after the user clicks this button (which must be done on the backend servlet I believe). What is the best way to this? Should my  onSignIn method in javascript create a form with the email/name of the user and submit, and then grab this from a getPost in servlet? Or should I be going about this a different way?